# Adding WMS layer in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: wms, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to layer data from Kartverket (Norwegian Mapping Authority) over my Mapbox map, but currently the only thing I'm getting returned is a transparent image. I'm wondering if there are anyone else that have done anything similar that could help me figure out what could be wrong with the request.

Code

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('wms-test', {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': [
            'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.dybdedata2?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=Dybdekontur&styles=default&format=image/png&transparent=TRUE&version=1.3.0&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=53.1,-13.6,85.94,42.8&width=256&height=256'
        ],
        'tileSize': 256
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'wms-layer',
        'type': 'raster',
        'source': 'wms-test',
        'paint': {}
    });
});
```

Link to the GetCapabilities for the WMS:
https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.dybdedata2?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are out of luck here. If you look at the result of `getCapabilities` request, you'll see that `Dybdekontur` layer is available only in `EPSG:4258` projection. This effectively means you can't use it in MapBox.

When you are adding WMS source, it's URL is specified in `tiles` option, which means it will be used for fetching tiles from WMS service. Each tile has its own `bbox`, depending on location and zoom. This means you can't specify fixed `bbox` like you did with `bbox=53.1,-13.6,85.94,42.8`.

Proper way for specify `bbox` for tiles retrieved from WMS service is to use `{bbox-epsg-3857}` placeholder string (see https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/6.3.0/tile-url-templates.html). As the name of the placeholder tells, it's in `EPSG:3857` projection, so you can't use it for your desired layer.

But there is `Dybdedata2` layer in your WMS source that is available in `EPSG:3857` projection. So this code:

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken='your access token';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11',
  zoom: 10,
  center: [10, 64]
});

var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({
  showZoom: true
}); 
map.addControl(nav, "bottom-right");
 
map.on('load', () => {
  map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
    'type': 'raster',
    'tiles': [
      'https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.dybdedata2?bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&crs=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=Dybdedata2'
    ],
    'tileSize': 256
  });
  map.addLayer(
    {
      'id': 'wms-test-layer',
      'type': 'raster',
      'source': 'wms-test-source',
      'paint': {}
    }
  );
});
```

will give you this result:

[image]

**EDIT:** Although `getCapabilities` request says that `Dybdekontur` layer is available only for `EPSG:4258` projection, I tried also `EPSG:3857` and it actually works! It's just that layer is available only for zoom levels 13 and higher. That's how it looks like at zoom 14:

[image]

Comment: The CRS is reported as being supported in the root layer (parent of all other layers)

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for clarification.